# Image build failed

Tags: rhel8, appimage-builder

i am trying to create a image in RHEL 8.7 Vm but i am encountering this error. i checked both services that were running fine cockpit and osbuild-composer but image was not created even i tried to create am image via cli mode but it also showed FAILED status.

[image]

how to get rid of this error?

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11286032)